# jQuery Animate on mouseenter and Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have a simple color animation with [jquery.color](http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js). This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fx_link').bind({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            $(this).attr('originalColor', $(this).css('color'));
            $(this).animate({ color: "#999999" }, 'fast');
        },
        mouseleave: function(e) {
            $(this).animate({ color: $(this).attr('originalColor') }, 'fast');
            $(this).removeAttr('originalColor');
        }
    });
});
```

And it is quite good. But, the animation is for menu items. If the mouse is on an item, the animation start. Then the mouse click and the page is refreshed. The mouse is on  link but it is not moving. Sooner as the mouse moves just one pixel the mouseenter event is fired (even if the mouse is already on the link) and there is an animation that i consider a bug.

I would need somethink like:

```
$(this).bind({ mouseenter: function(e) {

    if( __ mouse is not already over $(this) __ ) 

        $(this).animate(...); } });
```

I have tried with some set state on mouseenter, mouseover but.. no way

### EDIT:

full example. save this as `h.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.fx_link').bind({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            console.log("enter");
            $(this).attr('originalColor', $(this).css('color'));
            $(this).animate({ color: "#999999" }, 'fast');
        },
        mouseleave: function(e) {
        
            console.log("leave");
            $(this).animate({ color: $(this).attr('originalColor') }, 'fast');
            $(this).removeAttr('originalColor');
        
        }
    });
});


</script>
<body>

<a class="fx_link" href="h.html">this is a link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying that when the page reloads, or a new page loads, the mouseenter event fires once more ?

Comment: i'm preparing an example, better

Comment: Sounds like what you are experiencing is normal functionality. Most browsers dont remember the mouse in between page states, if that makes sense. If you refresh a page with a mouse over a link, that link wont be highlighted on the refreshed page until you move it even 1 pixel.

Comment: Try this: bind a function on mousemove and inside this function bind the mouseenter

Comment: I think there is one bug in the code: not sure, but if mouse enters while color is being animated, originalColor may pickup one color used during the animation so you may loose the original color forever. To be sure to avoid this move the `$(this).attr('originalColor', $(this).css('color'));` out of the mouse enter and never do the removeAttr(..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I'm on mobile phone so the code might be wrong (not tested).

**EDITED** (and tested now)

```
// fix: bind mousemove to document, not links, sorry!
$(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
    $('.fx_link').bind('mouseenter', function(event) {
         //....
    }
    $(this).unbind(event);
});
```

**EDITED**

- Full example with handling of 2 different mouseEnters one if [at page refresh] mouse is already inside link (just set the color), one when coming from outside (animate color).
- Fixed originalColors bug by setting originalColors for all the links at start.
- Used named functions instead of anonymous functions so it was easy to unbind (and looks more clear too).

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var $links=$('.fx_link');

    // save ALL originalColors so they are fixed forever
    $links.each(function() {$(this).attr('originalColor', $(this).css('color'));});

    $(document).bind('mousemove', handleMove);
    $links.bind('mouseenter', firstMouseEnter);
    $links.bind('mouseleave', anyMouseLeave);

    function handleMove(event) { // When mouse moves in document
        console.log("first move - setting up things..");
        $(document).unbind('mousemove',handleMove); // remove myself (no need anymore)
        $links.bind('mouseenter', otherMouseEnter); // istall second mouseenter
        $links.unbind('mouseenter',firstMouseEnter); // remove first mouseenter
    }

    function firstMouseEnter(event) { // Called before mouse is moved in document
        console.log("first enter");
        $(this).css('color','#999');
    }

    function otherMouseEnter(event) { // Called after mouse is moved in document
        console.log("other enter");
        $(this).animate({ color: "#999" }, 'fast');
    }

    function anyMouseLeave(event) {
        console.log("leave");
        $(this).animate({ color: $(this).attr('originalColor') }, 'fast');
    }

});


</script>
<body>

<a class="fx_link" href="h.html">this is a link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow, almost! it seems to work. but it seems to misses the first mouseenter after the refresh

Answer (score 1):

Is the point of this to fade the menu item with a class of "fx_link" to another color when it is hovered over? In that case you could most likely just use css3 transitions with .fx_link:hover. Then you could customize the transition as needed.

```
a.fx_link{
color:red;
-webkit-transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-transition-property: background color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition-property: color;
  -o-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-transition-property: background color;
  -ms-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 2.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;    
}

a.fx_link:hover{
    color:blue;
-webkit-transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-transition-property: background color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -o-transition-property: color;
  -o-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-transition-property: background color;
  -ms-transition-duration: 2.5s;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 2.5s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

​

Comment: i know that. but i thought to avoid for a while the css3 transition for cross compatibility with old browser. stupid thought?